# Error when trying to install packages via pacman on Arch Linux WSL

Tags: arch-linux, pacman, windows-subsystem-for-linux, pgp

I am using Arch for Windows Subsystem for Linux build. Whenever I try to install a specific package (e.g. python) it displays a Y/n prompt:

```
:: Import PGP key [KEY], "[Name]", created: [date]? [Y/n]
```

It does not matter if I press Y or N. The commandline always displays an error:

```
error: failed to commit transaction (unexpected error)
Errors occurred, no packages were upgraded.
```

Do you have any ideas on how to fix it?

Comment: Did you initialize trusted keys before installing packages? Try to run this `pacman-key --init` and `pacman-key --populate`, then update/install packages.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Thanks! It worked. I used `pacman-key --init` earlier but now I know that I should have typed `pacman-key --populate` after.

Comment: @Biswapriyo , I did it , and now it shows `failed to retrive some files` . And in the above logs , `The requested URL returned error: 404` . The mirror link to all of those packages were :`mirror.cse.iitk.ac.in`

Comment: i have the same issue